# Minimizing Budgets with R (solver)

Tags: r, optimization, solver, minimization

This is the function discussed at [Optimization of budget allocation in R (formerly Excel Solver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215682/optimization-of-budget-allocation-in-r-formerly-excel-solver/50216136#50216136)

```
  NrwGes <- function(Budget, Speed, maxnrw, cpcrp) {
  BudgetA <- Budget[1]
  BudgetB <- Budget[2]
  BudgetC <- Budget[3]
  BudgetD <- Budget[4]
  BudgetE <- Budget[5]

  MaxNRW <- c(90, 40, 40, 25, 15)
  Speed <- c(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
  cpcrp <- c(6564, 4494, 3962, 4525, 4900)

  TV <- BudgetA*1000/cpcrp[1]
  Catchup <- BudgetB*1000/cpcrp[2]
  YT <- BudgetC*1000/cpcrp[3]
  FB <- BudgetD*1000/cpcrp[4]
  Display <- BudgetE*1000/cpcrp[5] 

  a <- TV^Speed[1]/(1+abs((TV)^Speed[1]-1)/(MaxNRW[1]*0.98))
  b <- Catchup^Speed[2]/(1+abs((Catchup)^Speed[2]-1)/(MaxNRW[2]*0.98))
  c <- YT^Speed[3]/(1+abs((YT)^Speed[3] -1)/(MaxNRW[3]*0.98))
  d <- FB^Speed[4]/(1+abs((FB)^Speed[4]-1)/(MaxNRW[4]*0.98))
  e <- Display^Speed[5]/(1+abs((Display)^Speed[5]-1)/(MaxNRW[5]*0.93))

  Ges <- a+(100-a)/100*b+((100-a)/100*(100-b)/100*c)+((100-a)/100*(100-b)/100*(100-c)/100*d)+((100-a)/100*(100-b)/100*(100-c)/100*(100-d)/100*e)
  return(Ges)
}

proj <- function(x) 5000 * x / sum(x)
st <- proj(rep(1, 5))
f <- function(x) NrwGes(proj(x))
res <- optim(st, f, lower = 0 * st, method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(fnscale = -1))
```

With the optimization approach i am able to maximize "Ges". But my boss has also another requirement for the tool. He wants to "Ges", which is returned by the function to have a static value (for example 70) and the Budget has to be minimized to archieve that value. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: If `obj` is your original objective maximize `obj - alpha * min(70 - obj, 0)` where `alpha` is a number that you will need to adjust until you get the desired answer.

Comment: This seems to require you to specify a different optimization problem -- a constrained optimization problem. This is one possible formulation: 

min Budget
wrt Speed, maxnrw, cpcrp, ...
such that
     Ges=70

Comment: sorry G.Grothdieck, I don´t understand it. Where do i use this variables? Do I have to minimize proj(res$value) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
NrwGes <- function(Budget, val_Ges = 70, bool_Print = FALSE) 
{
  BudgetA <- Budget[1]
  BudgetB <- Budget[2]
  BudgetC <- Budget[3]
  BudgetD <- Budget[4]
  BudgetE <- Budget[5]
  
  MaxNRW <- c(90, 40, 40, 25, 15)
  Speed <- c(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
  cpcrp <- c(6564, 4494, 3962, 4525, 4900)
  
  TV <- BudgetA*1000/cpcrp[1]
  Catchup <- BudgetB*1000/cpcrp[2]
  YT <- BudgetC*1000/cpcrp[3]
  FB <- BudgetD*1000/cpcrp[4]
  Display <- BudgetE*1000/cpcrp[5] 
  
  a <- TV^Speed[1]/(1+abs((TV)^Speed[1]-1)/(MaxNRW[1]*0.98))
  b <- Catchup^Speed[2]/(1+abs((Catchup)^Speed[2]-1)/(MaxNRW[2]*0.98))
  c <- YT^Speed[3]/(1+abs((YT)^Speed[3] -1)/(MaxNRW[3]*0.98))
  d <- FB^Speed[4]/(1+abs((FB)^Speed[4]-1)/(MaxNRW[4]*0.98))
  e <- Display^Speed[5]/(1+abs((Display)^Speed[5]-1)/(MaxNRW[5]*0.93))
  
  Ges <- a+(100-a)/100*b+((100-a)/100*(100-b)/100*c)+((100-a)/100*(100-b)/100*(100-c)/100*d)+((100-a)/100*(100-b)/100*(100-c)/100*(100-d)/100*e)
  term1 <- (Ges - val_Ges) ^ 2
  term2 <- sum(Budget) ^ 2
  val_Ret <- term1 * 10 ^ 9.5 + term2
  
  if(bool_Print == TRUE)
  {
    print("Ges")
    print(Ges)
    print("Budget")
    print(Budget)
    print("sum(Budget)")
    print(sum(Budget))
  }
  
  return(val_Ret)
}

library(DEoptim)
obj_DEoptim_Iter1 <- DEoptim(fn = NrwGes, lower = rep(0, 5), upper = rep(10 ^ 6, 5),
                             control = list(itermax = 10000))

obj_DEoptim_Iter2 <- DEoptim(fn = NrwGes, lower = obj_DEoptim_Iter1$optim$bestmem * 0.90,
                             upper = obj_DEoptim_Iter1$optim$bestmem * 1.1,
                             control = list(itermax = 10000))

NrwGes(Budget = obj_DEoptim_Iter2$optim$bestmem, val_Ges = 70, bool_Print = TRUE) 

[1] "Ges"
    par1 
69.99996 
[1] "Budget"
     par1      par2      par3      par4      par5 
829.68879 269.90853 272.25272 154.00195  84.03696 
[1] "sum(Budget)"
[1] 1609.889
   par1 
2591748
```