# Optimize with constraints

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I have a function which allocates a budget by maximizing some parameters. I have 5 different inputs which are stored in `st`. However I want to give constraints these values can take.

I have 5 channels, for example TV, YouTube, Facebook, Display and Streaming, but i only want a maximum 1000€ in TV of a budget of 5000€.

```
BruteforcesmallNRW <- function(budget) {
    proj <- function(x) budget * x / sum(x)
    st <- proj(rep(1, 5))
    f <- function(x) NrwGes(proj(x))
    res <- optim(st, f, lower = 0 * st, method = "L-BFGS-B", upper = c(1000, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf), control = list(fnscale = -1))
    x <- res$value
    y <- proj(res$par)
    z <- c(x, y)
    return(z)
}
```

The function works fine, but however ignores my constraints. Can you help me?

This is my custom function:

```
NrwGes <- function(Budget) {
    BudgetA <- Budget[1]
    BudgetB <- Budget[2]
    BudgetC <- Budget[3]
    BudgetD <- Budget[4]
    BudgetE <- Budget[5]

    MaxNRW <- c(data$MaxNRWTV[i], data$MaxNRWCatchup[i], data$MaxNRWYT[i], data$MaxNRWFB[i], data$MaxNRWDisplay[i])
    Speed <- c(data$SpeedTV[i], data$SpeedCatchup[i], data$SpeedYT[i], data$SpeedFB[i], data$SpeedDisplay[i])
    cpcrp <- c(data$CpGRPTV[i], data$cpGRPCatchup[i], data$cpGRPYT[i], data$cpGRPFB[i], data$cpGRPDisplay[i])

    # MaxNRW <- c(data$MaxNRWTV[i], data$MaxNRWYT[i], data$MaxNRWFB[i], data$MaxNRWDisplay[i], data$MaxNRWCatchup[i])
    # Speed <- c(data$SpeedTV[i], data$SpeedYT[i], data$SpeedFB[i], data$SpeedDisplay[i], data$SpeedCatchup[i])
    # cpcrp <- c(data$CpGRPTV[i], data$cpGRPYT[i], data$cpGRPFB[i], data$cpGRPDisplay[i], data$cpGRPCatchup[i])

    TV <- BudgetA*1000/cpcrp[1]
    Catchup <- BudgetB*1000/cpcrp[2]
    YT <- BudgetC*1000/cpcrp[3]
    FB <- BudgetD*1000/cpcrp[4]
    Display <- BudgetE*1000/cpcrp[5]

    a <- TV^Speed[1]/(1+abs((TV)^Speed[1]-1)/(MaxNRW[1]*0.98))
    b <- Catchup^Speed[2]/(1+abs((Catchup)^Speed[2]-1)/(MaxNRW[2]*0.98))
    c <- YT^Speed[3]/(1+abs((YT)^Speed[3] -1)/(MaxNRW[3]*0.98))
    d <- FB^Speed[4]/(1+abs((FB)^Speed[4]-1)/(MaxNRW[4]*0.98))
    e <- Display^Speed[5]/(1+abs((Display)^Speed[5]-1)/(MaxNRW[5]*0.93))

    obj <- a+(100-a)/100*b+((100-a)/100*(100-b)/100*c)+((100-a)/100*(100-b)/100*(100-c)/100*d)+((100-a)/100*(100-b)/100*(100-c)/100*(100-d)/100*e)
    return(obj)
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, as I don't know which package `NrwGes` belongs to. Or is it a user-defined function?

Comment: this is a custom function. I added the code. Thank you :-)

Comment: @MarkusLnGa: you're using a projection as suggested in [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216136/316644)... so your constraints are applied to the unprojected values ans so you should use "unprojected" upper bounds as well... unfortunately you can't because proj function is not invertible

Comment: I suggest you to change approach and use another optim function allowing for constraints, like the one in nloptr package which I showed you (coincidence?) in [the same post mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216595/316644)

Comment: thank you, i totally forgot about that post. I am still working on that tool :-|. Thank you very much!